# Insert value after using greater than condition in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formatting, conditional-formatting

I am stuck on Excel and it's condition.

I have a huge set data and want to use Excel's conditions rule to apply any necessary change.

The rule is:

if the values in column are > 69.99, then put "1" beside it's column. If the value in that column is < 69.99, then put "0" beside it's column. So for example refer to the table. The program should look at all the values and see if it's greater than 69.99 or less than 69.99 and insert 1 or 0 beside it's appropriate column.

```
 Column1 | APPLIED CHANGE | Column 2 |
 70      -> 1
 130     -> 1
 49      -> 0
 682     -> 1
 39      -> 0
 596     -> 1
 29      -> 0
```

Comment: =IF(A1<=69.99,0,1)

Comment: Should work simple if logic like `=IF(A2>69.99,1,0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This says if A1 is blank, return a blank result, if A1 is less than or equal to 69.99, return 0, and for any other scenario, return 1.

`=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",IF(A1<=69.99,0,1))`

[image]

Comment: Litle alternative: `=IF(A1="","",--(A1>=69.99))`. You currently got the expected results reversed btw =)

Answer (score 1):

As you tagged `Conditional-Formatting` so use below to highlight bigger than 69.99

```
=$A1>69.99
```

If you just want show `1` or `0` in other column then use-

```
=IF(A2>69.99,1,0)
```

Comment: Little alternative: `=--(A2>69.99)` =)